# Override JsonDeserializer Behavior

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

The generator has created a field of type OffsetDateTime:

```
@Nullable
@ElementName("DocDate")
private OffsetDateTime docDate;
```

But the server actually returns dates in the format: YYYY-mm-dd i.e. `2021-03-07`

When using the generated code I get the following warnings:

```
WARN - Not deserializable: 2021-03-07
```

What is the correct way to override the deserialization of these fields? Or have these fields deserialize correctly?

Comment: Hi Connner, welcome to SO. Is the service OData V4? Also, is the field in the service defined as Edm.DateTimeOffset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `OffsetDateTime` should have both a date and a time. The data your service responds with is lacking the time part. As per the [OData V4 ABNF](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/cs01/abnf/odata-abnf-construction-rules.txt), this is not allowed (assuming your service is a V4 service):

```
dateTimeOffsetValue = year "-" month "-" day "T" hour ":" minute [ ":" second [ "." fractionalSeconds ] ] ( "Z" / SIGN hour ":" minute )
```

One way to solve this is to change the property type. You could either:

1. Change it to `Edm.Date` in the specification
2. Or change it to `LocalDate` in the generated code.

Of course this only makes sense if the service will always respond with a date.

---

Edit: If you really need to register a custom type adapter (e.g. because the service violates the JSON format) you could override the `GsonVdmAdapterFactory`:

```java
public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create( @Nonnull final Gson gson, @Nonnull final TypeToken<T> type )
{
    if( LocalDate.class.isAssignableFrom(rawType) ) {
        return (TypeAdapter<T>) new CustomLocalDateTypeAdapter();
    } else {
        return super.create(gson, type);
    }
}
```

However, this also requires changing the generated code, because there is currently no convenience to pass a custom type adapter as parameter. Change `@JsonAdapter(com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odatav4.adapter.GsonVdmAdapterFactory.class)` to reference your custom factory.

Still, I'd recommend using one of the above workarounds until the service is fixed.

Comment: The SAP B1 definition lists it as `<Property Name="DocDate" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset"/>` but actually returns dates without any time information. I can modify the generated code to reflect it. I was wondering if there were a more elegant way of handling this but the above works.

Comment: If the service always responds with a `Date` then I think adapting the spec until it is fixed by the service is the best way to go. If for some reason the existing parsing logic is not a solution, I expanded my answer on how to register custom type adapters if it is absolutely necessary.

Comment: Makes sense, unfortunately I don't think this spec will be changed anytime soon. I'll just keep modifying the client code as needed. Thanks for the help!